# FabricJs iText top and left position based on text and not by bounding box

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, fabricjs

When I'm trying to get the top and left values of an text object in FabricJs, I get the values back of the bounding box. But what I would like to know is the top and left values of the text itself and not the bounding box.

I added a image for a better understanding of this problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPMgo.jpg

I tried to find a solution, but I couldn't find exactly what I was looking for. I hope you can help me out.